# Structuring Normalized JSON response in Redux store and mapping to React component props

Tags: json, reactjs, redux, normalization

Just recently, our team began structuring our JSON payload in a normalized fashion. I am most used to working with nested data in React components and even in the reducer, but I see the benefits here (less connected components re-rendering, simplified reducer code, and easier tests) and I am excited to start using this approach. I do however, have some confusion with the state shape after my first try.

Let's start with the shape of the payload -

```
{
      "data": {
        "advisors": {
          "allIds": [
            2
          ], 
          "byId": {
            "2": {
              "active": true, 
              "avatar_url": null, 
              "country": "US", 
              "email": "demo@gmail.com", 
              "first_name": "George Michael", 
              "full_name": "George Michael Bluth", 
              "id": 2, 
              "last_name": "Bluth", 
              "time_zone": "US/Central"
            }
          }
        }, 
        "opportunities": {
          "allIds": [
            "100-3", 
          ], 
          "byId": {
            "100-3": {
              "created": "Fri, 29 Sep 2017 20:00:40 GMT", 
              "program_id": 3, 
              "prospect_id": 100
            }
          }
        }, 
        "programs": {
          "allIds": [ 
            3
          ], 
          "byId": {
            "3": {
              "abbr": "CAP", 
              "end_date": null, 
              "funnel_id": 2, 
              "id": 3, 
              "launch_date": "Sat, 11 Mar 2017 00:00:00 GMT", 
              "name": "Certificate in Astral Projection", 
              "period_end": null, 
              "period_start": null, 
              "program_level_abbr": "NCC", 
              "school_id": 2, 
              "virtual": false
            }
          }
        }, 
        "prospects": {
          "allIds": [
            2,
          ], 
          "byId": {
            "2": {
              "advisor_id": 3, 
              "contact_attempt_count": 0, 
              "contact_success_count": 0, 
              "do_not_call": false, 
              "do_not_email": false, 
              "do_not_mail": false, 
              "email": "adavis.est@hotmail.com", 
              "first_name": "Antonio", 
              "id": 2, 
              "inactive": false, 
              "last_name": "Davis", 
              "phone": {
                "area_code": "800", 
                "extension": "70444", 
                "number": "3575792"
              }, 
              "priority": 10.0, 
              "referred_by_prospect_id": null, 
              "third_party": false
            },
          }
        }
      }, 
      "pagination": {
        "page_number": 1, 
        "total": 251
      }
    }
```

The normalized payload is structured so that advisors, opportunities, programs, and prospects are siblings and not ancestors. They're all nested one level inside of "data".

Then, in my "prospects" reducer I initialize the prospects state as an object with the following keys: fetching, failure, and entities. The first two are UI data and entities will house the response (advisors, opportunities, programs, and prospects).

```
const initialState = {
  fetching: false,
  failure: false,
  entities: null,
};

function prospects(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case constants.prospects.REQUEST_PROSPECTS:
      return { ...state, fetching: true };
    case constants.prospects.RECEIVE_PROSPECTS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        fetching: false,
        entities: action.data,
      });
    case constants.prospects.REQUEST_PROSPECTS_FAILURE:
      return { ...state, fetching: false, failure: true };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

And now for the red flag that brought me here - my props and internal component state seem oddly structured. I mapStateToProps like so:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  prospects: state.prospects,
});
```

This has resulted in me accessing advisors, opportunities, programs, and prospects like this:

```
this.props.fetching
this.props.failure
this.props.prospects.entities.advisors.allIds.length
this.props.prospects.entities.opportunities.allIds.length
this.props.prospects.entities.programs.allIds.length
this.props.prospects.entities.prospects.allIds.length
```

My understanding is that with a normalized approach things are typically housed under this.props.entities and ui data in this.props.ui. Is the problem that I am getting all this data back from my prospects action and reducer and not separate actions and reducers? I want to reducer the accessor chain in my components, because it's become very error prone and hard to read. Would it be better to query for each entity with separate XHRs and reducers?

I know there a lot of good resources on this approach including videos from DA. But I haven't found an answer to all of these questions in combination. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Summary

I'm suggesting that you refactor your state to look like:

```
{
  network: {
    loading: false,
    failure: false
  },
  advisors: { allIds, byId },
  opportunities: { allIds, byId },
  programs: { allIds, byId },
  prospects: { allIds, byId },
}
```

To do this, you'll want a reducer for each key in the state. Each reducer will handle its portion of the normalized payload and otherwise ignore actions.

### Reducers

Network.js:

```
function network(state = { loading: false, failure: false }, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case constants.REQUEST_PAYLOAD:
      return { ...state, fetching: true };
    case constants.RECEIVE_PAYLOAD:
      return { ...state, fetching: false, failure: false };
    case constants.prospects.REQUEST_PROSPECTS_FAILURE:
      return { ...state, fetching: false, failure: true };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Prospects.js:

```
function prospects(state = { allIds: [], byId: {} }, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case constants.RECEIVE_PAYLOAD:
      // depending on your use case, you may need to merge the existing
      // allIds and byId with the action's. This would allow you to 
      // issue the request multiple times and add to the store instead
      // of overwriting it each time.
      return { ...state, ...action.data.prospects };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Repeat the prospects reducer for each other section of the state.

---

### Note

I'm assuming your payload comes back in that fashion from a single API call, and that you're not stitching that together from separate calls for each sibling (advisors, opportunities, programs, and prospects).

---

## Details

In order to store your payload in the store, I would recommend writing separate reducers that each handle a different part of the state returned by your API call.

For `prospects`, you should *only* store the `prospects` portion of the payload and throw out the rest.

So instead of...

```
case constants.prospects.RECEIVE_PROSPECTS:
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    fetching: false,
    entities: action.data,
  });
```

You should do...

```
case constants.prospects.RECEIVE_PROSPECTS:
  return { 
    ...state,
    fetching: false,
    entities: action.data.prospects,
  };
```

Then have a similar reducer for each of the other types of data returned by your API call. Each of these reducers will process *the exact same actions*. They'll only handle the portion of the payload that they care about, though.

Finally, in your `mapStateToProps`, `state.prospects` will only contain the prospect data.

As a side note--assuming I'm correct about the payload being delivered by a single API--I would rename your action constants to `REQUEST_PAYLOAD`, `RECEIVE_PAYLOAD` and `REQUEST_PAYLOAD_FAILURE`, or something equally generic.

One more suggestion: you can move your `fetching` and `failure` logic into a `NetworkReducer` that only has the job of managing success/failure/loading for the API request. That way, each of your other reducers only has to handle the `RECEIVE` case and can just ignore other actions.

Comment: you've given me exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much. Having been used to a denormalized approach, nested data, and one reducer per API call, I couldn't see that one reducer was my problem. I will take on all of your advice! But, I do have some small doubts:

Comment: 1. REQUEST_PAYLOAD, RECEIVE_PAYLOAD, and REQUEST_PAYLOAD_FAILURE will only work as names if that component were the entire app - other components will make API calls and they won't use these actions. I am thinking to name the calls after the components, how does REQUEST_PROSPECTS_TABLE_DATA ect sound?

Comment: You should name the actions after the API. If you have multiple API calls, then tailor the actions to each.

Comment: 2. A networkReducer is just what I was looking for, but network connectivity in this case only applies to this component (table). It is possible that this component will still be fetching (true), while other components have completed fetching (false) and they are displayed in the UI earlier. I feel I need to name space the network activity as well. This would look like this.props.prospects.networkActivity. Would you agree? Many thanks for your help! I am amazed at your and the rest of stack overflows patience and willingness to understand others problems and give help!

Comment: Luke, about the action names. You are right I make one api call, but it is to a normalized API. While the route looks like api/prospects, it returns normalized data for prospects, advisors, programs, opportunities. Because it returns all of these, the name REQUEST_PROSPECTS_PAYLOAD seems wrong to me.

Comment: The network reducer depends on your specific case. If you're only ever executing one network call at any given time, then just storing data for the current request is reasonable. If you'll be executing calls in parallel, then you may want to do either A. Keep a history of all requests or B. Keep a map of request type to network state. 

Comment: Naming is notoriously hard. I wouldn't get too hung up on it. If you would qualify all of that as "prospect data" even though not all of it is strictly "prospects", then REQUEST_PROSPECT_DATA might be fine.

Comment: Thanks a million, no further questions =)

Comment: Glad to help! 